# Python exchangelib - How to Capture/Save email as png

Tags: python, exchangelib

Need your assistance in saving the email as .png. The code below will get the body of the email, but it is unable to get a screenshot in the body of the email.

```
with open(r"output.txt", "w") as output:
    for item in fromfolder.filter(is_read=False):
        output.write('{}\n'.format(item.body))
        item.is_read = True
        item.save()
        item.move(archieve)
```

Have tried saving email as eml and msg, but nothing is working out.

Answer (score 0):

`item.body` contains the entire body of the email message, not just the image contained in the body.

`exchangelib` does not offer methods to parse the body of the email. You'll need to use other packages for that.

I think your best bet would be to parse the `item.mime_content` field which contains the raw email content. You can use e.g. `email.parser.BytesParser.parse_bytes(mime_content)` from https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html. This will return an [EmailMessage](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage) with your PNG image.

Comment: Thanks for you're reply Erik Cederstrand, but its not working with the email parser.

Comment: What is not working and what did you try? You’ll need to add your attempts at parsing, error messages, and the actual data you are trying to parse, to get more help.